# in python turtle the function I defined is not detected

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from turtle import Turtle , Screen

positions = [(0,0),(-20,0),(-40,0)]
move_distance = 20
UP = 90
DOWN = 270
LEFT = 180
RIGHT = 0

class Snake():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.create_snake()

    def create_snake(self):
        for position in positions:
            add_segment(position)

    def add_segment(self,position):
        t = Turtle("square")
        t.penup()
            
        t.color("white")
        t.goto(position)
        self.segments.append(t)

    def extend(self):
        self.add_segment(self.segments[-1].position())


    def move(self):
        for num in range(len(self.segments)-1,0,-1):
            new_x = self.segments[num - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.segments[num - 1].ycor()
            self.segments[num].goto(new_x,new_y)
        self.segments[0].forward(move_distance)

    def up(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != DOWN:
            self.segments[0].setheading(UP)
    def down(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != UP:
            self.segments[0].setheading(DOWN) 
    def left(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != RIGHT:
            self.segments[0].setheading(LEFT)
    def right(self):
        if self.segments[0].heading() != LEFT:
            self.segments[0].setheading(RIGHT)
```

NameError: name 'add_segment' is not defined
ı just started to learn python and ıdk where the problem is if you can explain with details it would be nice.It needs text to publish the question so ı write this part for that

Comment: it should be ``self.add_segment``

Comment: The code that you posted does not (by itself) throw the error that you report. Please post a [mcve] rather than just a fragment of code which potentially hides the actual error.